# Is it possible to do something like beforeall with mustache?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have the following template:

```
<div class="photoList">
    {{#photos}}
        <img src="{{columnPhoto.url}}" data-zoom-url="{{original_size.url}}"/>
    {{/photos}}
</div>
```

Sometimes {{#photos}} is empty or not set, in those cases, I don't want to add the div `.photolist`, is this possible?

Comment: Just pull the `{{#photos}}` outside of the div?

Comment: phtotos is an array so then I will loop the DIV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{#photos.length}}
<div class="photoList">
    {{#photos}}
        <img src="{{columnPhoto.url}}" data-zoom-url="{{original_size.url}}"/>
    {{/photos}}
</div>
{{/photos.length}}
```